# Static UITableView madness

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, static

I have a static view, its a settings view. It has 3 sections

```
section 1 has 3 rows
section 2 has 1 row
section 3 has 1 row
```

I wired up the UISwitch's in each row, which all work fine. The last row s3-r1 I need to react to a selection. Its a UITableViewController do I override didDeselectRowAtIndexPath  and added:

```
if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {
    // do something here - yes there's more than a comment in here
}
```

nothing happened. So I did this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("section \(indexPath.section) row \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Doesn't matter where I start, the first row I select prints nothing, then they're all out of order. For example.

```
user action             = println output
touch section 1 - row 1 = (nothing+
touch section 1 - row 2 = section 0 row 0
touch section 1 - row 3 = section 0 row 1
touch section 2 - row 1 = section 0 row 2
touch section 3 - row 2 = section 1 row 0
```

Next I created an outlet to the cell I want to react and tried this instead:

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
if cell == cellOutlet {
   println("!!!")
}
```

This does print but randomly from different cells

I've been googling for hours and I have no idea what's going on. Why are the seemingly in random order? Help Obi-wan

Comment: "Doesn't matter where I start, the first row I select prints nothing, then they're all out of order" Actually they are exactly right. You are logging in _deselect_. That doesn't run until you select something _else_. So you select the first row, nothing is deselected. You select the second row, and the _first row is deselected_ and you get "section 0 row 0", which is exactly correct.

Comment: #^$%#$#& How many times can I do that . . . I'm an idiot, thanks

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes. You did collect all the data and provide all the info, so you did all the right work and you asked the question with enough data. That's good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you have overridden the wrong method. It isn't `didDeselect` you care about — it's `didSelect`. Override *that* method and you'll be fine.